# Building a penalty system for overdue library books - how do I keep account of the fines per user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When a `User` has a `Booking` which is overdue, I want to give the `User` a penalty of £1 per day for each overdue `Booking`.

So far I've defined an overdue `Booking` as one which has a `booking_end` datetime attribute less than `Time.now` AND still has an `active` boolean set to `true`.

**What would be the correct way to approach this penalty system?** Is it necessary to create a new table for the penalties? In this case, how would I make the fine increase per `Booking` every day?

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    def overdue?
        due_date_absolute < Time.now.strftime("%d %B %Y") && self.active == true
    end

    def due_date_absolute
        self.booking_end.strftime("%d %B %Y")
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't store any data for this, it's purely the output of a computation. Just calculate the penalty in real-time each time you need to know it.

```
def overdue?
    due_date_absolute < Time.now.strftime("%d %B %Y") && self.active == true
end

def due_date_absolute
    self.booking_end.strftime("%d %B %Y")
end

def overdue_rate
  1.99 # $1.99 per day; hard-code this or pull it from a settings file, etc.
end

def fine
  # Calculate number of days over-due, multiply by overdue_rate
  overdue_rate * ((Time.now - self.booking_end) / 1.days)
end
```